# Extracting href ID from block of code using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

From the following code, I want to target the href and collect the ID number at the end of the link, setting that number as a variable named "VARIABLE" (in this block of code, the number would be "2019786"). I've used requests to collect the page in my program and I also have imported BeautifulSoup4. Also, this block of code could change from page to page, thus changing the href ID number, so I was thinking when collecting this number, use something like:

/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=%

```
<a class="d2l-link d2l-outline d2l-left" href="/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=2019786" title="Enter CHEM-1315-018 - Lab-CHEM 1315-001">CHEM-1315-018 - Lab-CHEM 1315-001</a>
```

Thanks in advance, Jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a pattern for matching the `href` attribute value:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^/d2l/lp/ouHome/home\.d2l\?ou=(\d+)')
```

<sup>(if the url itself is also a variable, change your regex to just `ou=(\d+)`)</sup>

and use it in both `find()` and afterwards for extracting the `ou` value:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '<a class="d2l-link d2l-outline d2l-left" href="/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=2019786" title="Enter CHEM-1315-018 - Lab-CHEM 1315-001">CHEM-1315-018 - Lab-CHEM 1315-001</a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

pattern = re.compile(r'^/d2l/lp/ouHome/home\.d2l\?ou=(\d+)')
link = soup.find('a', class_='d2l-link', href=pattern)

print pattern.search(link['href']).group(1)
```

Prints:

```
2019786
```

`(\d+)` here is a [*capturing group*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) that matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup and a simple regex to get the id if the pattern of the URLs is going to be the same.

The code would look something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = """<a class="d2l-link d2l-outline d2l-left" href="/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=2019786" title="Enter CHEM-1315-018 - Lab-CHEM 1315-001">CHEM-1315-018 - Lab-CHEM 1315-001</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
href_link = soup.a['href']
match = re.search(r'ou=(\d*)', href_link)
if match:
    print int(match.group(1)) # do whatever you want with it here
else:
    print "no id found"
```

Note that you don't need to specify the whole URL to get the id, as the id would be always sent  as a parameter after "ou=".